# Add new column to a table without constraint in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to `add` a `column` with the `same value` across the rows to a table. I use this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD MyColumnName VARCHAR(20) NULL
DEFAULT 'A201412'
WITH VALUES
```

It almost works fine but it creates some stupid constraint to a column. Other existing columns do not have any constraints. How to create a column without a constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "stupid" constraint is what the `DEFAULT` keyword is really used for.
Using `DEFAULT` when you create a column means that that value will be used when no value is specified in an `INSERT` for the column, for example

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  a Int
, b Varchar(5) DEFAULT 'foo'
);

INSERT INTO test(a) VALUES (1)
```

will generate the row

```
a | b
1 | foo
```

instead of the row

```
a | b
1 | NULL
```

As Gordon already said, don't add the `DEFAULT`, then use an `UPDATE` to put the initial value in the new column

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD MyColumnName VARCHAR(20);

UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyColumnName = 'A201412'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just don't add the `default` clause.  Simply use:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD MyColumnName VARCHAR(20);
```